# android twitter integration using AsyncTask

Tags: android

plz help me in integrating twitter in my android app account using AsyncTask . I m following androidhive tutorial on integrating twitter account but i am getting Network on main thread exception.
Thanks in advance :D

This is the link of code

http://www.androidhive.info/2012/09/android-twitter-oauth-connect-tutorial/

and this is my MainActivity.java

```
import twitter4j.Twitter;
import twitter4j.TwitterException;
import twitter4j.TwitterFactory;
import twitter4j.User;
import twitter4j.auth.AccessToken;
import twitter4j.auth.RequestToken;
import twitter4j.conf.Configuration;
import twitter4j.conf.ConfigurationBuilder;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.SharedPreferences.Editor;
import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Html;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    // Constants
    /**
     * Register your here app https://dev.twitter.com/apps/new and get your
     * consumer key and secret
     * */
    static String TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY = ""; // place your cosumer key here
    static String TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET = ""; // place your consumer secret here

    // Preference Constants
    static String PREFERENCE_NAME = "twitter_oauth";
    static final String PREF_KEY_OAUTH_TOKEN = "oauth_token";
    static final String PREF_KEY_OAUTH_SECRET = "oauth_token_secret";
    static final String PREF_KEY_TWITTER_LOGIN = "isTwitterLogedIn";

    static final String TWITTER_CALLBACK_URL = "oauth://t4jsample";

    // Twitter oauth urls
    static final String URL_TWITTER_AUTH = "auth_url";
    static final String URL_TWITTER_OAUTH_VERIFIER = "oauth_verifier";
    static final String URL_TWITTER_OAUTH_TOKEN = "oauth_token";

    // Login button
    Button btnLoginTwitter;
    // Update status button
    Button btnUpdateStatus;
    // Logout button
    Button btnLogoutTwitter;
    // EditText for update
    EditText txtUpdate;
    // lbl update
    TextView lblUpdate;
    TextView lblUserName;

    // Progress dialog
    ProgressDialog pDialog;

    // Twitter
    private static Twitter twitter;
    private static RequestToken requestToken;

    // Shared Preferences
    private static SharedPreferences mSharedPreferences;

    // Internet Connection detector
    private ConnectionDetector cd;

    // Alert Dialog Manager
    AlertDialogManager alert = new AlertDialogManager();

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);

        cd = new ConnectionDetector(getApplicationContext());

        // Check if Internet present
        if (!cd.isConnectingToInternet()) {
            // Internet Connection is not present
            alert.showAlertDialog(MainActivity.this, "Internet Connection Error",
                    "Please connect to working Internet connection", false);
            // stop executing code by return
            return;
        }

        // Check if twitter keys are set
        if(TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY.trim().length() == 0 || TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET.trim().length() == 0){
            // Internet Connection is not present
            alert.showAlertDialog(MainActivity.this, "Twitter oAuth tokens", "Please set your twitter oauth tokens first!", false);
            // stop executing code by return
            return;
        }

        // All UI elements
        btnLoginTwitter = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLoginTwitter);
        btnUpdateStatus = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnUpdateStatus);
        btnLogoutTwitter = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLogoutTwitter);
        txtUpdate = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtUpdateStatus);
        lblUpdate = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lblUpdate);
        lblUserName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lblUserName);

        // Shared Preferences
        mSharedPreferences = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(
                "MyPref", 0);

        /**
         * Twitter login button click event will call loginToTwitter() function
         * */
        btnLoginTwitter.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // Call login twitter function
                loginToTwitter();
            }
        });

        /**
         * Button click event to Update Status, will call updateTwitterStatus()
         * function
         * */
        btnUpdateStatus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Call update status function
                // Get the status from EditText
                String status = txtUpdate.getText().toString();

                // Check for blank text
                if (status.trim().length() > 0) {
                    // update status
                    new updateTwitterStatus().execute(status);
                } else {
                    // EditText is empty
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Please enter status message", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                            .show();
                }
            }
        });

        /**
         * Button click event for logout from twitter
         * */
        btnLogoutTwitter.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // Call logout twitter function
                logoutFromTwitter();
            }
        });

        /** This if conditions is tested once is
         * redirected from twitter page. Parse the uri to get oAuth
         * Verifier
         * */
        if (!isTwitterLoggedInAlready()) {
            Uri uri = getIntent().getData();
            if (uri != null && uri.toString().startsWith(TWITTER_CALLBACK_URL)) {
                // oAuth verifier
                String verifier = uri
                        .getQueryParameter(URL_TWITTER_OAUTH_VERIFIER);

                try {
                    // Get the access token
                    AccessToken accessToken = twitter.getOAuthAccessToken(
                            requestToken, verifier);

                    // Shared Preferences
                    Editor e = mSharedPreferences.edit();

                    // After getting access token, access token secret
                    // store them in application preferences
                    e.putString(PREF_KEY_OAUTH_TOKEN, accessToken.getToken());
                    e.putString(PREF_KEY_OAUTH_SECRET,
                            accessToken.getTokenSecret());
                    // Store login status - true
                    e.putBoolean(PREF_KEY_TWITTER_LOGIN, true);
                    e.commit(); // save changes

                    Log.e("Twitter OAuth Token", "> " + accessToken.getToken());

                    // Hide login button
                    btnLoginTwitter.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                    // Show Update Twitter
                    lblUpdate.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    txtUpdate.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    btnUpdateStatus.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    btnLogoutTwitter.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                    // Getting user details from twitter
                    // For now i am getting his name only
                    long userID = accessToken.getUserId();
                    User user = twitter.showUser(userID);
                    String username = user.getName();

                    // Displaying in xml ui
                    lblUserName.setText(Html.fromHtml("<b>Welcome " + username + "</b>"));
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // Check log for login errors
                    Log.e("Twitter Login Error", "> " + e.getMessage());
                }
            }
        }

    }

    /**
     * Function to login twitter
     * */
    private void loginToTwitter() {
        // Check if already logged in
        if (!isTwitterLoggedInAlready()) {
            ConfigurationBuilder builder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
            builder.setOAuthConsumerKey(TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY);
            builder.setOAuthConsumerSecret(TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET);
            Configuration configuration = builder.build();

            TwitterFactory factory = new TwitterFactory(configuration);
            twitter = factory.getInstance();

            try {
                requestToken = twitter
                        .getOAuthRequestToken(TWITTER_CALLBACK_URL);
                this.startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri
                        .parse(requestToken.getAuthenticationURL())));
            } catch (TwitterException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            // user already logged into twitter
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Already Logged into twitter", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Function to update status
     * */
    class updateTwitterStatus extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        /**
         * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
         * */
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Updating to twitter...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        /**
         * getting Places JSON
         * */
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
            Log.d("Tweet Text", "> " + args[0]);
            String status = args[0];
            try {
                ConfigurationBuilder builder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
                builder.setOAuthConsumerKey(TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY);
                builder.setOAuthConsumerSecret(TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET);

                // Access Token 
                String access_token = mSharedPreferences.getString(PREF_KEY_OAUTH_TOKEN, "");
                // Access Token Secret
                String access_token_secret = mSharedPreferences.getString(PREF_KEY_OAUTH_SECRET, "");

                AccessToken accessToken = new AccessToken(access_token, access_token_secret);
                Twitter twitter = new TwitterFactory(builder.build()).getInstance(accessToken);

                // Update status
                twitter4j.Status response = twitter.updateStatus(status);

                Log.d("Status", "> " + response.getText());
            } catch (TwitterException e) {
                // Error in updating status
                Log.d("Twitter Update Error", e.getMessage());
            }
            return null;
        }

        /**
         * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog and show
         * the data in UI Always use runOnUiThread(new Runnable()) to update UI
         * from background thread, otherwise you will get error
         * **/
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            // dismiss the dialog after getting all products
            pDialog.dismiss();
            // updating UI from Background Thread
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Status tweeted successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                            .show();
                    // Clearing EditText field
                    txtUpdate.setText("");
                }
            });
        }

    }

    /**
     * Function to logout from twitter
     * It will just clear the application shared preferences
     * */
    private void logoutFromTwitter() {
        // Clear the shared preferences
        Editor e = mSharedPreferences.edit();
        e.remove(PREF_KEY_OAUTH_TOKEN);
        e.remove(PREF_KEY_OAUTH_SECRET);
        e.remove(PREF_KEY_TWITTER_LOGIN);
        e.commit();

        // After this take the appropriate action
        // I am showing the hiding/showing buttons again
        // You might not needed this code
        btnLogoutTwitter.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        btnUpdateStatus.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        txtUpdate.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        lblUpdate.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        lblUserName.setText("");
        lblUserName.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        btnLoginTwitter.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    /**
     * Check user already logged in your application using twitter Login flag is
     * fetched from Shared Preferences
     * */
    private boolean isTwitterLoggedInAlready() {
        // return twitter login status from Shared Preferences
        return mSharedPreferences.getBoolean(PREF_KEY_TWITTER_LOGIN, false);
    }

    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
    }

}
```

Comment: Please post your code here...

Comment: put those line in back ground thread where its occur.

Comment: Have alook it here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6343166/android-os-networkonmainthreadexception

Comment: put your login call in asynctask

Comment: I have added my MainActivity class code above

Answer (score 0):

You might got this error most probably in 4.0 device or IF the http conncetion is taking too long to respond.

if you dont know asynctask then simple solution will be

```
public static boolean isAuthenticated(Context context) {
    new Thread() {
    @Override 
    public void run() {
    TwitterPrefrences twitterPref = new TwitterPrefrences(context);     
    String token = twitterPref.getTwitterAuthToken();
    String secret = twitterPref.getTwitterAuthTokenSecrate();

    AccessToken a = new AccessToken(token,secret);
    Twitter twitter = new TwitterFactory().getInstance();
         twitter.setOAuthConsumer(Constants.TWITT_CONSUMER_KEY,Constants.TWITT_CONSUMER_SECRET);
    twitter.setOAuthAccessToken(a);

    try {
        twitter.getAccountSettings();
        return true;
    } catch (TwitterException e) {
        return false;
    }
  }
 }.start();

}
```